# Porting a 32-bit Win32 DLL driver to 64-bit when a 64-bit DLL is unavailable in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a legacy 32-bit Win32 DLL driver that interfaces with a test equipment. I possess the API header file for this driver, and I dynamically load the DLL at runtime within my C++ test application using Visual Studio 2019. My goal is to port this test application to 64-bit architecture, but there is no corresponding 64-bit DLL available for this driver.

What would be the most effective approach for porting this legacy driver to a 64-bit environment, specifically within a C++ application developed using Visual Studio 2019? Are there any best practices or tools that can assist in this process? I'm particularly interested in any experiences or insights from those who have faced a similar situation.

Comment: The most effective approach is to go back to the supplier and ask them for a 64-bit DLL. The second most effective approach is to go back to the supplier and ask them for the source code, and hope it is 64-bit clean. Anything else is months to years of work.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I already asked that. However, they said they do not have a plan to develop a 64 bit driver. I was looking for a wrapper solution.

Comment: You cannot "wrap" 32-bit code inside a 64-bit wrapper, they are fundamentally incompatible - this is why Windows has `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)`. Your only solutions are to have a native 64-bit driver or to do IPC to an entirely separate 32-bit process.

Comment: İ found a COM solution to access 32 bit COM from 64 bit application in https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/267554/Using-32-bit-COM-Object-from-64-bit-Application

Comment: Sure, but that's because COM is IPC. Does your driver expose a COM interface? If not, I don't see how that's relevant.

Comment: The driver DLL does not expose a COM interface. A converter layer can to be implemented to provide COM interface. I know this is not an elegant solution. However, it seems to be the only one.

Comment: @CemPolat a COM interface solves the problem of talking to the driver from other software. But you still need a way to run the driver. If don't have a 64 bit update of the old driver and use the old 32 bit driver when you don't have 32 bit hardware, or emulation thereof, to run it on then you're talking to dead code.

Comment: @candied_orange 32 bit DLL in concern is a NI-VISA driver that provides instrument control on the test equipment to perform measurements. VISA provides a standard API for controlling various instruments and communication interfaces (such as LAN) using a common set of commands. It abstracts the low-level communication details and allows you to send SCPI commands to instruments and receive their responses.Therefore, it is not a driver for a PC hardware resource. Instead it is a communication layer for the remote hardware. COM can provide layer to communicate 64 bit application with the driver.